# Drop random effects parameters from output table in Stata

Tags: stata, mixed-models

I want to create a regression table (using `esttab`) from a mixed-effects regression estimated via `xtmixed` in Stata, but I want the output without the random effects parameters. How can I drop the random effects parameters from the output table? E.g., in the case of two variables...

`xtmixed (Dependent Variable) (Independent variable) || (Grouping Variable)`)

... I don't want the `lns1_1_1` and the `lnsig_e` values in my `esttab`-table. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `keep()` and a `drop()` option. For example:

```
webuse productivity, clear

xtmixed gsp private emp hwy water other unemp || region: || state:, mle
estimates store m1

// check result names
matrix list e(b)

// with -keep()- option
estout m1, keep(private emp hwy water other unemp gsp:_cons)

// with -drop()- option
estout m1, drop(lns1_1_1:_cons lns2_1_1:_cons lnsig_e:_cons)
```

In the context of multiple equation estimation, resulting matrices have elements with two-part names. The general form is *equation-name:varname*. The result of `matrix list` shows this. Afterwards, just use the appropriate names in the `keep()` and `drop()` options.

See **[U] 14.2 Row and column names** for more details on the naming conventions.

(Recall `esttab` is a wrapper for `estout`.)

Comment: Thanks! That's what I am looking for. How can I add the intercept? The command 'keep(_cons private emp hwy water other unemp)' seems not to work as it again adds the random effects parameters...

Comment: Perhaps it would be also interesting if you show how to do the same with the 'drop()' command. Especially when the number of independent variables is large this could be shorter... Thank you!!!

Comment: I added an example with the `drop()` option, but it's nothing more than an extension of the `keep()` case. Even if the number of independent variables is large, at some point you would need to spell them out. If you do so with a local macro, then you could use it repeatedly. `estout` will happily take it. For example, ``estout m1, keep(`mylocal' gsp:_cons)``.